# Select, option with collapse does not work in Safari

Tags: javascript, html, safari, bootstrap-4

I have this code with bootstrap 4 (latest) and it works fine in IE 11 and FireFox but not in Safari och Mac. The content is always hidden if I select something in the dropdown in Safari.

If I select "Select Invoice address", I would like to hide the address and if "Service AB" is selected I want to show the address.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<select class="custom-select d-block w-100 mb-3" id="invoice-select">
  <option class="case" value="">Select Invoice address</option>
  <option class="" value="" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#invoice1">Service AB</option>
</select>
<div class="invalid-feedback">
  Please select a invoice address.
</div>
<div class="collapse indent" id="invoice1">
  <input type="text" class="form-control mb-3" id="invoice-site" name="invoice-site" value="invoice Center" placeholder="invoice Center" readonly>
  <input type="text" class="form-control mb-3" id="invoice-street" name="invoice-street" value="test invoice street" placeholder="test invoice street" readonly>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6 mb-3">
      <input type="text" class="form-control mb-3" id="invoice-zip-code" name="invoice-zip-code" value="111 22" placeholder="111 22" readonly>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 mb-3">
      <input type="text" class="form-control mb-3" id="invoice-city" name="invoice-city" value="NY" placeholder="NY" readonly>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please add code to show a [mcve]. It currently does nothing in Chrome

Comment: Thanks, your snippet works fine in FireFox. Does this not working in Chrome (Same as Safari)?

Comment: That is correct. And in Firefox it TOGGLES when I change the select so I have to select service AB twice to hide the form

Comment: jQuery would be `$("#invoice-select").on("change",function() { $('#invoice1').toggle(this.value == "Service AB"); })` if you gave a proper value

Answer (score 0):

How about this with a little jquery onChange action.
I put a value on the select options to have a reference. (Tested on Chrome, Safari)

```js
$('#invoice-select').on('change',function(){
  $('#invoice1').toggle(this.value == "Service AB");
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<select class="custom-select d-block w-100 mb-3" id="invoice-select">
  <option class="case" value="">Select Invoice address</option>
  <option class="" value="Service AB" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#invoice1">Service AB</option>
</select>
<div class="invalid-feedback">
  Please select a invoice address.
</div>
<div class="collapse indent" id="invoice1">
  <input type="text" class="form-control mb-3" id="invoice-site" name="invoice-site" value="invoice Center" placeholder="invoice Center" readonly>
  <input type="text" class="form-control mb-3" id="invoice-street" name="invoice-street" value="test invoice street" placeholder="test invoice street" readonly>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6 mb-3">
      <input type="text" class="form-control mb-3" id="invoice-zip-code" name="invoice-zip-code" value="111 22" placeholder="111 22" readonly>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 mb-3">
      <input type="text" class="form-control mb-3" id="invoice-city" name="invoice-city" value="NY" placeholder="NY" readonly>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why not `$('#invoice1').toggle(this.value == "Service AB");`

Comment: Still does not explain why the BS did not

Comment: Reading the documentation it says "You can use a link with the href attribute, or a button with the data-target attribute. In both cases, the data-toggle="collapse" is required." It's for LINK or BUTTON but not for a option in a select. [Boostrap 4.0 Collapse](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/)